# pipe(), fork(); execve(); I look for the same behavior than bash for `cat | ls`

Tags: c

I the code below, i'm looking for the same behavios as `cat | ls` in bash.
But in my program, the fork with `cat` won't end until i send him `ctrl+D`.

I don't understand at all why that append.
When i `dup2()` into the child's, that work fine, but i want my `dup2()` call's in the parent program.

I close however properly my piped fd after each use in the parent and close the unused one in the first child

````
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int     save_and_restore_fd(int action)
{
    static int  fds[3] = {-1};

    if (action == 0)                                //Save stdin/out/err
    {
        fds[STDIN_FILENO] = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
        fds[STDOUT_FILENO] = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
        fds[STDERR_FILENO] = dup(STDERR_FILENO);
    }
    else if (action == 1)                           //Restore stdin/out/err
    {
        dup2(fds[STDIN_FILENO], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fds[STDIN_FILENO]);
        dup2(fds[STDOUT_FILENO], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fds[STDOUT_FILENO]);
        dup2(fds[STDERR_FILENO], STDERR_FILENO);
        close(fds[STDERR_FILENO]);
    }

    return (1);
}

int main()
{
    int fds[2];
    char *args1[2] = {"/bin/cat", NULL};
    char *args2[2] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};

    pipe(fds);                                  //Open pipe
    save_and_restore_fd(0);                     //save stdin/out/err

    dup2(fds[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fds[1]);

    if (fork() == 0)                            //Execute cat into a child
    {
        close(fds[0]);
        execve("/bin/cat", args1, NULL);
    }
    save_and_restore_fd(1);                     //load stdin/out/err

    dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fds[0]);

    save_and_restore_fd(0);                     //save stdin/out/err
    if (fork() == 0)                            //Execute ls into a child
    {
        execve("/bin/ls", args2, NULL);
    }
    save_and_restore_fd(1);                     //load stdin/out/err
    while (wait(NULL) > 0);                     //Wait all child end
    return (0);
}```
````

Comment: You need to close the unused descriptors in the parent and children.

Comment: @Barmar I already close the unused fd in the parent and the children

Comment: You should be calling `dup2()` in the child processes, not the parent.

Comment: I can't do it this way in my project :/

Comment: You need to. Each child process needs different redirections to the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Just before my `wait` loop, i need to close `stdin`.
The `cat` in the first fork use the original `stdin`, then i need to close it for `cat` to end by himself.